# blender opengl 3

Tags: windows, opengl

Today i tried to download the latest version of blender but it gives me a problem on opengl, telling me that i need at least opengl 3.3, even though i should have opengl 4.
So I found a modification on the internet to get it started by adding a .dll file.
Now blender starts but does not use any graphics card and then the program jerks.
Do you think it is the fault of the opengl?

**pc specifications**
Sis: Windows 10 Pro |
CPU: Intel Pentium G4560 |
GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti / Intel HD Graphic 610 |
RAM: 8GB DDR4

*PS: i have updated drivers more than once and the monitor is connected with a VGA*

Comment: Have you tried to updated the driver for your integrated GPU as well ([available on Intel's website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/de/download/29817/Intel-Grafikfenster-10-DCH-Treibern?product=98910))?

Comment: yes Robert. I have updated everything

Comment: Can you open [Blender 2.79b](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/) (.zip portable version)? If yes, please use *Help > Save System Info* and attach the file to your question.

Comment: Blender 2.79b don't start. An error appears in the console but I can't see it

Comment: Then something is very broken on your system. Could you try to open the installation directory of one of the Blender 2.8x versions, remove the OpenGL.dll and then double-click on `blender_debug_gpu.cmd`. This will start Blender in debug mode and create log files. Once Blender closes the Windows Explorer should open and show you two files, one of them should be the system info file.

Comment: I took a picture and basically the problem is this: Error Totblock: 15

Comment: ok i'm trying._

Comment: you are a genius. blender no longer lags

Comment: maybe the drivers you sent me were the ones that were missing

Comment: That would be the most likely explanation and solution.